# SAPUI5: ODatav4 add static data to data downloaded from API

Tags: odata, sapui5

Let's say we have some list of items that are automatically downloaded from API

```
          <ComboBox items="{'model>Users'}">
            <c:Item
              key="{model>Id}"
              text="{model>FirstName} {model>LastName}"
            />
          </ComboBox>
```

Works really well. **But how can I now expand the data downloaded with oData by adding some more objects?**

The things that I've tried:

- Trying to find some sort of "onDownloadCompleate" function so that when the users are downloaded I can attach some more. I couldn't find such function in oData v4.
- Getting the data from the model and attaching additional objects to it. I couldn't found how I can do this.

The only solution I see is to not use oData at all and just download the users using normal API call.

Comment: Have you tried the [dataReceived event](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding%23events/dataReceived) on your list binding? That should be the "onDownloadComplete" you were looking for.

Comment: if it was me, I would add the extra data to the oData results in the back end if that was possible. Easier binding and only one place to check for results instead of 2 for easier maintenance